# What network manager to use for the Xfce4 Panel to see my current conection state?

Tags: indicator, network-manager, xfce, system-tray, xfce-panel

I have installed Xubuntu desktop on top of initial Lubuntu 12.04 installation.

How can I select between the wireless networks and how to see the app in the panel?

[image]

I used Xfce in the past but I do not remember how to add it (I had it by default then I guess)

I have installed `Wicd` and added it in a launcher

[image]

It says "without system tray icon". But I'm thinking about exactly that: a systray "live" icon/applet for the panel that I'm missing for the moment in Xfce.

It is the most common thing, present by default in all ubuntu flavors - even booting from live cd displays it

[image]

How can I have that in Xfce Panel?

(`Wicd` is excellent but I still want to see "live" any changes to my connection.)

Update: I have noticed that **after installing `wicd` I have a  "live" Wicd systray icon in Lubuntu/LXDE (LXPanel)**

[image]

[image]

but I don't have that in Xubuntu/Xfce/Xfce4-Panel

Comment: flagged by OP to close as too localised.

Comment: Locking of this thread is not good. Even a cursory knowledge of the information domain shows that many people are in the same boat. Discussing xfce4 on a Ubuntu thread is certainly NOT localised since Ubuntu can use xfce4 - as is evident from this thread. Had it been allowed to continue it could and would have been a lot more helpful  - especially since wicd is NOT a plugin replacement for network-manager , network-manager-gnome and certainly not nm-applet.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a program to manager wireless networks called `wicd`:

** Instalation**

`sudo apt-get install wicd`

**Configuration**

> Configuration of Wicd is extremely simple, and automatic for wired
> clients.
>
> To configure a wireless connection: Open the Wicd network
> manager in Applications > Internet > Wicd Network Manager, or you may add it as a launcher to Xfce Panel.

[image]

[image]

> See if the wireless network you're looking for shows on the list. If it is a hidden network, click the down arrow next to the Network button, and type in the ESSID of
> the network.
>
> If the network you want to connect to is listed, press the "Connect" button next to it. > If you get the message "This network requires encryption to be enabled." hit OK

[Source](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/moinmoin/Wicd%20on%20Ubuntu)

You can also try network-manager network-manager-gnome

Comment: yes, i have wicd, see edit. i see in synaptic that `network-manager-gnome` is there. how to see it in xfce panel?

Comment: Just launch it from the console: network-manager-gnome, and see if that works for you

Comment: i had just installed `wicd`. (see what i really want in the question, launching from console is not ok. but:) `wicd` is so good (didn't knew and did not care about it when i used to have what i ask for here) that i might keep it as the best solution even if i get an answer to the present question . thnx

Comment: so i'll edit your answer accordingly if you don't mind, i might set it the definitive: there is no tray icon etc, as the app clearly states but it can be added as launcher to the xfce panel

Comment: If you run from a console: `wicd-client` do you get what you want?

Comment: no it doesn't show tray in xfce4-panel. i see that in usr/bin there are wicd-client and wicd-gtk but both open the same program. i am very satisfied with wicd. but can you tell me what progamme is running by default in the tray and displays the network activity? is the most common stuff. at least i want to know the name of it. what is it in gnome for example, or in lxde, or xfce. is it the same?

Comment: I do not use wicd, but the default network tool for gnome is nm (networkmanager) and the icon you see on the toolbar is nm-applet